# Explode a MySQL result set in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to store, retrieve and create a list from a MySQL result set where some items appear in more than one position, it also needs to default new items to the end of the list therefore it would be better not to control it using a separate table.

```
Product  Position
Prod1    1 3
Prod2    2
```

To create the list

- Prod1
- Prod2
- Prod1

It seems overkill but I can't find another way that would work.  If I went from a MySQL result set to an array how could I explode the items with multiple positions into new array items that would represent my list?

Comment: every position has just one product? also, are there more positions in one row separated by empty space like in your example?

Comment: The format is flexible, one item per position but some items are in more than one sub category and the user can define the order for every list item and sub list items independently (drag drop reordering)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    array('product' => 'prod 1', 'position' => '1 3'),
    array('product' => 'prod 2', 'position' => '2'),
);

$data_ordered = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach (explode(' ', $row['position']) as $subrow) {
        $data_ordered[$subrow] = $row['product'];
    }
}

ksort($data_ordered);

var_dump($data_ordered);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need two tabels. First `producs` with id and name

```
id name
1  Prod1
2  Prod2
```

Also you need the order of the list. Maybe like this

```
list
id items
1  1,2,1
```

If you want to print the list with id 1. Get items from the database and do a `explode(',', $items);`. Now get the name for every item id. If you don't have a lot of products get all products at once and store them in an array for faster access.

**Update**

It not a good design but if you want it in one table:

```
id name  lists
1  Prod1 1:1,1:3
2  Prod2 1:2
```

where lists contains `list_id:position,[list_id:position], ...`. But to view a list you have to fetch all products and check if it's in list 1. Make an array with position => product_row so you can use `ksort()`.

Comment: The thing this doesn't address is when Prod3 is added it will no be on the menu.  The old system controlled the menu manually so items had to be specifically added to it within the CMS, I want to automate it hence trying to keep it within the product table.  The main thing is a product can be in multiple sub categories and the order of every item can be changed (it's not alphabetic for example)

Comment: down vote? wtf? Someone really knows how to stop people from helping. Closing stackoverflow for today...

Comment: It's not a single level list it is sub categories where a product can appear more than once so you can't just add it to the end.  It has given me something else to think about though, similar approach but using multiple lines with 1 line per sub category

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't me who downvoted.  It may be because you offered an alternative approach but I am very open to that, trying to answer the problem rather than just the specific question is equally valid IMO